# How does inputting iptables error in it's rule, by putting in duplicate listing?

Tags: iptables

I added a couple of iptables rules which went fine, but then it keeps duplicating another listing. You can see in the snapshot that this rule was correctly added:
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s 174.122.18.122 -j DROP
But, when I attempting to put in this rule:
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s 117.0.0.0/4 -j DROP
112.0.0.0/4 was added instead, which is a duplicate listing of what is on line 107. 
[Iptables Snapshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1cnO.gif)
I can added in singular IPs, but if I try an IP block it renders this duplicate of 112.0.0.0/4 and I then have to remove it. I don't understand what could be the issue, any help would be appreciated.
This is a CentOS 6.4 (Final) server with Plesk 11.0.9

Answer (score 0):

*iptables* just standardizes the [CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation) of `117.0.0.0/4` to `112.0.0.0/4` by clearing all bits of the IP address but the most significant four ones, as signified by the network mask.

This is done since the value of the remaining 28 bits is irrelevant when evaluating whether the rule in question matches a certain packet.

Comment: Ok, so how can I prevent the block of 117.0.0.0/4 from trying to login to my server using iptables? I have tried removing 112.0.0.0/4 altogether and replacing it with 117.0.0.0/4, but that just returns to 112.0.0.0/4.

Comment: The network blocks of `117.0.0.0/4` and `112.0.0.0/4` are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you, so how then is an IP such as 117.192.81.44 still able to make hacking attempts on my server?

Comment: I have no idea but you can add a logging rule in order to verify that incoming packets from that IP address range are indeed dropped.

Comment: I can see from the logs that 117.192.81.44 is not dropped, which is why I am asking so many silly questions. Please pardon my lack of knowledge, but it does not appear that blocking 112.0.0.0/4 is doing anything with regards to blocking the ips in 117.*.*.* which is actually more important to me at this point than is the 112 block. Does ANYONE know why after removing 112.0.0.0/4 from the iptables and then trying to add 117.0.0.0/4 it returns to the listing of 112.0.0.0/4 ? I am having a hard time getting my head around that.

Comment: Nevermind, and thanks.... for some reason I was thinking /4 would cover 16,777,216 IPs when in reality its much more. So I removed the 112.0.0.0/4 and replaced it with 112.0.0.0/8 which allowed me to block what I really wanted to; 110.0.0.0/8, 111.0.0.0/8, 112.0.0.0/8, and 114.0.0.0/8 thru 125.0.0.0/8 . Thanks again!